# mandelbrot set vertical display

Tags: java, graphic, fractals, mandelbrot

Just wondering how to display a mandelbrot set vertically, like a mandelbrot set as this is positioned horizontally:

[image: 'brot]

I was thinking more like viewing the smaller dimensions from the vertical axis.

Comment: You mean, just rotate it 90 degrees?

Comment: Please clarify your question *greatly*. How are you getting the image now? Are you generating it? Downloading it? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Perhaps utilize the `TiltHeadSideways` API.  Other possible options are co-ordinate transformation as suggested by Tomasz Nurkiewicz or an `AffineTransform` for a custom painted component or new image.  Please narrow down the use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exactly the same equations as you would use to display horizontal Mandelbrot set but switch `y` with `x` and `x` with `-y`.

Comment: thank you, and do you know how i would be able to generate 3d mandelbrot sets?

Comment: thank you, by any chance, do you think quantum superpositions can be emulated with fractal superpositions?

Answer (score -1):

Pseudocode:

```
if width > height:
    transpose_coordinates(pixels)
```

or like Ivella said

```
if width > height:
    rotate(img, 90)
```